# RadioGroup not working in iteration

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.somelist}" var="item" indexVar="rowIndex" start="{!v.Start}" end="{!v.End}">
                      <lightning:radioGroup name="{!'radioGroup'+item.rowIndex}"
                        aura:id="{!item.rowIndex}"
                        label="{!item.Name}"
                        options="{!item.statusOption}"
                        value="{!item.Status__c}"
                        required="true"
                        type="radio"/> 
                   </aura:iteration>
```

When there is more than one element in the list. Then only one radio button is selected.

Comment: just an fyi: you cant assign aura id's dynamically in an aura:iteration

Comment: ok, let us assume I removed it.

Comment: it is picklist filed

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<lightning:radioGroup name="{!'radioGroup'+rowIndex}"
```

The iterator var should be the unique rowIndex. Make sure they are unique throughout the page, or you can get other odd behavior. HTML5 depends on this name being globally unique to identify radio groups.